# Criando e Consumindo uma REST API

Tags: php, api, xamarin

Bom dia, estou tentando criar uma API, para fazer uma validação de usuario e senha, para utilizar no xamarin. Mas eu estou com duvidas, se eu quiser buscar um usuario x e uma senha x no banco de dados eu devo, passar todos os usuarios e senhas para um site ou existe alguma forma de realizar apenas a consulta de usuario x e essa senha x e apenas retornar esses dados de forma dinamica ? Desculpa se a pergunta ficou meio vaga, mas minha duvida está na logica, não estou entendendo muito bem com a API vai se comunicar de forma dinamica com o banco de dados.

Comment: Não acho seguro transmitir usuário e senha pela web. [Eis uma alternativa que acredito ser mais segura](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando uma API:

1. **Mobile**:envia os dados da tentativa de login (login e senha) para a API
2. **API**: realiza a consulta no banco de dados para verificar se existe uma entrada para usuário e senha informados (`SELECT * FROM user u WHERE u.login = '[login enviado]' AND u.senha='[senha digitada]'` . Retornará o resultado da consulta (se houve ou não resultado)
3. **Mobile**: exibe o resultado da tentativa (se existe ou não o usuário com a senha no banco)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, minha sugestão é que você crie uma api Rest Full, aplique algumas regras de segurança como criptografar os dados enviados guardando as chaves no app e no server REST, sobre a segurança se a API restfull for bem desenvolvida é seguro sim. Atualmente é uma das melhores formas de comunicar aplicativos com DBs.